# The scale in Qgis is not setting to feet

Tags: qgis, scale, print-composer, scale-bar

I am working in QGIS 2.4. I have changed the CRS of all the layers and in the project properties to `EPSG:102739 - NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet`.

I am in print composer trying to create a scale bar and I can not figure out why the scale is so off. I am trying to go from feet to miles and it just creates a really long scale bar. Basically `1 mi = 5280` is what I am going for I have already checked each layer and they are all in state plane 4203. I am not sure what I am missing. I checked other threads about scale in QGIS and I am still at a loss. I have tried flipping the conversion around and its still not working.

Edit 2: Sounds crazy is there a difference between Qgis for Windows and for Linux. I loaded the exact same data(just copied and pasted the file with the map and data) to a windows computer. Opened it and everything works fine.

Edit: The answer given [How to get correct scale values?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45218/how-to-get-correct-scale-values) does not address my issues. I have already done everything in that answer. All of my layers have been resaved with projection and the project projection has been changed.

[Using scale bar units in QGIS composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70104/problems-with-scale-bar-units-in-qgis-composer)

[What do I need to change to get scale bar units other than degrees?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38921/what-do-i-need-to-change-to-get-scale-bar-units-other-than-degrees)

[Why does QGIS scalebar show a wrong scale?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15901/why-does-qgis-scalebar-show-a-wrong-scale)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the coordinates we can see on your second screenshot (-99,30), I think that you changed the layer CRS in layer properties instead of properly reprojecting the data to state plane. Reproject the layers and try adding the scale bar then.

Comment: Hello, I have already done that. I choose my layer did a save as and changed the CRS that way, but it is still not working

Comment: If the extent of your layers is in degrees, you will never get feet as units. It looks like you have broken the shapefiles with false assigning of CRS.

Comment: With EPSG:102739, the extent of your data should be xMin,yMin 2694660.40;9820568.01 : xMax,yMax 3315333.67;10415697.74

Comment: Thanks!! I just changed everything to NAD 83 which works.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your .prj files in a text editor (Notepad, Notepad++, etc.) and then check out the text there.  If the CRS saved correctly it should say:
`PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",2296583.333333333],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",9842499.999999998],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-100.3333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",30.11666666666667],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",31.88333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",29.66666666666667],
    UNIT["Foot_US",0.30480060960121924],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","102739"]]`

If it doesn't match that then just replace your current .prj with this text.  That will set your projection correctly and then your units will be in feet.

Comment: Overwriting the .prj file is not generally good advice without knowing exactly what was done to the data before.

Comment: ... and it does not reproject any coordinates from one CRS to another.

Comment: He could still check to see if the .prj file is matching what it should be to see if QGIS is reprojecting correctly.